# How to delete data from a particular shard

Tags: elasticsearch

I have got a index with 5 primary shards and no replicas.

One of my shard(**shard 1**) is in unassigned state. When i checked the log file, i found out below error:

> 2obv65.nvd, _2vfjgt.fdx, _3e3109.si, _3dwgm5_Lucene45_0.dvm, _3aks2g_Lucene45_0.dvd, _3d9u9f_76.del, _3e30gm.cfs, _3cvkyl_es090_0.tim, _3e309p.nvd, _3cvkyl_es090_0.blm]]; nested: FileNotFoundException[_101a65.si]; ]]

When i checked the index, i could not find the **101a65.si** file for the **shard 1**.

I am unable to locate the missing `.si` file. I tried a lot but could not assign the **shard 1** again.

Is there any other way to make the **shard 1** assign again? or do i need to delete the entire **shard 1** data?

Please suggest.

Comment: @Val..could you please help me on this..

Comment: How ,any nodes are you running in the cluster? (also do you have at least 1 replica, and if so does it exhibit the same behavior?) Also, what version of Elasticsearch are you running?

Comment: there are 3 nodes running in the cluster. out of the 3, 2 nodes are data nodes and one is master node . there is no replica present in the cluster. 

i am using pretty old version i.e. 1.1.2.

Comment: What it looks like is that your shard is corrupted (something deleted this file when it shouldn't), the only way I can see to recover from this issue is to fully delete the shard

Comment: Exactly..how do i delete the data from the corrupted shard?

Also is it possible to clear the corrupted shard and use is again for the same index?

Answer (score 0):

Normally in the stack trace you should see the path to the corrupted shard, something like `MMapIndexInput(path="path/to/es/db/nodes/node_number/indices/name_of_index/1/index/some_file)` (here the **1** is the shard number)

Normally deleting `path/to/es/db/nodes/node_number/indices/name_of_index/1` should help the shard recover. If you still see it unassigned try sending this command to your cluster (normally as per [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/cluster-reroute.html), it should work, though I'm not sure about ES 1.x syntax and commands):

```
POST _cluster/reroute
{
  "commands" : [ 
        {
          "allocate" : {
              "index" : "myIndexName", 
              "shard" : 1, 
              "node" : "myNodeName", 
              "allow_primary": true
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do i need to restart the cluster so that the unassigned shards would get assigned?

as u have suggested, i have deleted the path: /var/opt/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch-sp/nodes/0/indices/twitter/1/index,

 however i am still seeing the affected shard as unassigned.

Comment: Have you tried the reallocation command? Do you still have an error in the logs?

Comment: it worked...i tried using the reallocation command and now the shard is in started state..

i could see this in the elasticsearch.log file: 

[2017-03-21 16:56:11,412][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Agent] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[twitter][1]] ...]).

Thanks @asettouf for your help..

Comment: @WellbornTellis Glad it worked as I never used Elastic 1.x! Also for others who might have the same issue, please tag this answer as being the answer to the question. Thanks